# Import multiple Vendors in one cell from xlsx to Odoo

Tags: excel, odoo, data-import, odoo-15

I am looking for a way to modify my excel file to import my vendors for my product templates via name. The problem is I have to seperate multiple names in excel so Odoo can recognize it as one name. So instead of having one Vendor name in one cell I want to have one cell with Vendor names, but recognized by odoo as individual. Is there any expression I can use?

I am aware of using keys and ids is way better but I have plenty of products and I dont know their keys

Instead of this :
[image: Instead of this format]

I need it to be like this: [image]

I want to prevent something like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding what you asked is not possible. The best option, in this case, is to create a new import script which parses the data in the cell accordingly and imports it into the product template.